# In free groups every non-abelian subgroup is self-centralizer

Tags: calculus, free-groups

A subgroup is Self-Centralizer if centralizer of the subgroup lies in subgroup. How to prove that for a free group every non-abelian subgroup is self-centralizer?

Comment: What are your thoughts about this? Have you already written an attempt to solve the question?

Comment: Isn't a centralizer of a group always in the group?

Comment: @M. Winter, a centralizer in a big group of a subgroup  may or may not be inside the subgroup.

Comment: I want to show that for a free group G and a non abelian subgroup of G like H : C(H)<H